# "javac" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: java, javac

При компиляции кода через командную строку, с помощью команды javac, выдается вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Путь к bin прописан. Вроде все правильно, но все равно выдает ошибку. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: покажите содержимое переменной **PATH**. проверьте куда у вас установлен JDK.

Answer (score 8):

**Причина ошибки** — заданы некорректные «переменные среды». Соответственно, необходимо указать правильные.

На рабочем столе откройте «Этот компьютер»:

1. Нажмите слева вверху «Свойства», затем слева в меню —
   «Дополнительные параметры системы».
2. В открывшейся вкладке «Дополнительно» в самом низу выберите
   «Переменные среды».
3. Откроется содержимое. Нажмите в каждом окне поочередно «Создать».
4. В окне «Новая пользовательская переменная» пропишите CLASSPATH.
5. Затем в окне «Новая системная переменная» укажите переменную PATH. В
   поле «Значение» пропишите директорию к пакету JDK.
6. Перезагрузите Windows.

Кроме того, чтобы выполнить Javac, вы можете в командной строке прописать полный путь к консоли. К примеру: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\javac.exe" MyFile.java`

[Источник](http://windowsten.ru/javac-ne-yavlyaetsya-vnutrennej-ili-vneshnej-komandoj/)

Comment: перезагружать не обязательно, достаточно cmd переоткрыть

Answer (score 1):

Если не помогло, добавление в CLASSPATH, то добавь тот же самый путь в PATH, если там уже что-то есть то добавляй через точку с запятой ';'

Comment: Было бы полезно предоставить пример

Answer (score 0):

Если после добавления путей ничего не поменялось, то сделай копии папок jdk в Programm Files/java и Programm Files(x86)/java

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение, путь в *переменных* мы прописываем до папочки bin, иначе работать не будет. Пример:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin
```

Перезагружаться скорее всего не понадобиться, но обязательно перезапустите командную строку.

Answer (score -1):

Надо перенести `JAVA_HOME` в самое начало переменной `PATH`, чтобы она была раньше стандартного пути, который прописался при установке:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```